# Splitting text into sentences

Tags: c#

I run into a problem while trying to parse my text into sentences.
Everything works fine is text is formatted this way: (random text)

> Much did had call new drew that kept. Limits expect wonder law she.
>     Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms.

Program parses text into 3 sentences.

But as soon as there is a line break in the middle of a sentence my program splits text incorrectly.

> Much did had call new drew that kept. Limits (new line her) expect wonder law she.
>   Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms.

Program parses text as 4 sentences.

My code:

```
public static void ReadData()
    {
        char[] sentenceSeparators = {'.', '!', '?'};

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFile))
        {
            string line = null;

            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                var split = line.Split(sentenceSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (var i in split)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Input #1:

```
Much did had call new drew that kept. Limits expect wonder law she.
Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms.
```

Output #1:

```
Much did had call new drew that kept
Limits expect wonder law she
Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms
```

Input #2:

```
 Much did had call new drew that kept. Limits expect 
 wonder law she.
 Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms.
```

Output #2:

```
Much did had call new drew that kept
Limits expect
wonder law she
Now has you views woman noisy match money rooms
```

Comment: You split per line right now, just read all -> split -> foreach the "splits" (write them on a line)

Comment: You could also use replace to replace newlines with nothing and sentenceSeperators with newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using `ReadLine`.  Use `ReadToEnd` instead.

```
public static void ReadData()
{
    char[] sentenceSeparators = {'.', '!', '?'};

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFile))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var split = line.Split(sentenceSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var i in split)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem - no need to feel stupid :) can you mark this answer as the answer ?  thanks

Comment: @Kloper, for big files reading by lines might be a better option. You would have to keep reading lines and concatenate them until it contains either of `sentenceSeparators`. Then extract sentence (use `Regex`). Continue adding new lines to what is left until the end of file.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentionen don't read it line by line if you want `\n` not to influence your splitting. Here is a version which does the job in 1 line:

```
string [] split = File.ReadAllText(dataFile).Split(sentenceSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Also: the display in the console is illusionary. Since it will display the "bad" sentence on 2 lines, but in the `split` array it will be on a single position!

```
Console.WriteLine(split.Length); // will display 3
```